# Dial diffrent number if phone call was not answered

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to call a secondary number if the call was not answered with Twilio  ?

```
const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;

const response = new VoiceResponse();
response.dial('415-123-4567');
response.ifNotAnsweredDial('415-123-4568'); //something like this
response.say('Goodbye');

console.log(response.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create something like this. Basically it is a sequential dialer. This is example code from Phil Nash on a sequential dialer here. Phil also calls out the [Find Me](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/findme) Twimlet (which is pre-built code).

[Useful Twilio Functions](https://github.com/philnash/useful-twilio-functions) (reference: hunt).

Comment: this seems to be the source code. https://github.com/dominikgehl/twimlets/blob/master/findme.php thank you!